# I'm getting a CS0234 "The type or namespace name "Services" does not exist in the namespace" even though I can see it in file structure

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was following a tutorial from Microsoft found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/create-razor-pages-aspnet-core/

At one point it instructs to add a folder under the root project called "Services". Within that folder is a file which needs to be accessed. Upon creating the project, another folder called "Models" was automatically created under the root folder.

I include the two lines at the top of another file:
`using RazorPagesDoughnuts.Services; using RazorPagesDoughnuts.Models;`

The Models statement works no problem. The Services statement generates the error. I have searched many resources and cannot find a solution.

I am using vscode 1.71.2 and .net 6.0

[Screenshot of file structure and statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6wRM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overfow. The red line under the name `services` in your image is a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace provided in the file `DoughnutService.cs` is probably not correct. Change that to `RazorPagesDoughnuts.Services` and check.

Answer (score 0):

In C# `using` statements are not based on file structure, but rather on namespaces. If there aren't any files with the statement `namespace RazorPagesDoughnuts.Services` in the project, then you will not be able to reference it in other files.

Make sure that `DoughnutService.cs` contains this namespace statement.

Comment: The top three lines of DoughnutService.cs are:  
using RazorPagesDoughnuts.Models;
namespace RazorPagesDoughnut.Services;
public static class DoughnutService {

Comment: @user20027912 It should be namespace RazorPagesDoughnut`s`.Services. Missing an **s**

Comment: ...That's embarrassing, thank you!

Comment: @user20027912 : Happens. You are welcome :)